# Twitter bootstrap popover shows on second hover and after but not first.

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a popover for a element after a ajax call has been made. Everything works as far as the ajax request and getting the data the first time, except no data is displayed when mouseover event happens. But when you hover over it again, You can see the data in the popover. I looked around on here and the web and found similar situation but less complex than my situation (No mouseover event and ajax). I understand that popover seems not to be initialized when I first call it in my situation. But the thing is, that I only can show it after the ajax is being called and it has to be mouseenter. Can anyone modify or guide me to showing the popover on first try. Thanks for any help (Please note that there are two on my page I am just showing 1 of them).

Element

```
<a href="#" rel="popover" id="users">Access Count:</a>
```

Javascript

```
 $('#users').mouseenter(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/album/feature_getaccess",
            data: { aID: modelID },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#users').popover({ content: result, html: true, placement: 'top', trigger: 'hover', delay: { show: 500, hide: 1500 } });
            }
        });
    });
```

Works fine after the second mouse in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the mouseenter stuff, the popover will still only appear on mouseenter, because you have it set to `trigger: 'hover'`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/album/feature_getaccess",
    data: { aID: modelID },
    success: function (result) {
        $('#users').popover({ content: result, html: true, placement: 'top', trigger: 'hover', delay: { show: 500, hide: 1500 } });
    }
});
```

Comment: One reason to do that might the OP doesn't want to simply load the contents

Comment: @ArunPJohny Maybe, but I believe that he probably does, because `modelID` comes from some scope outside his `mouseenter`, and since mouseenter is an event that can happen so frequently, I don't think he is worried about sending extra requests.